# macOS: saving images from the clipboard using `pngpaste` is faded and white

Tags: terminal, copy-paste, macos

When I take a screenshot on macOS, and use `pngpaste a1.png` to save it, the image is faded:
[image]

This only happens when I take a fullscreen screenshot using CMD+SHIFT+3, and not with CMD+SHIFT+4.

Comment: https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste/issues/16

Comment: That would appear to be a bug in the app, not something we could help with.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `gmktemp` (GNU `mktemp`) installed. (Using, e.g., `brew install coreutils`.)

The following is `zsh` code; It might or might not work with `bash`.

```
pngpaste () {
    local name="${1}" extension="${2:-png}" class="${3}" 
    test -z "$class" && class='«class PNGf»' 
    local stdout='' 
    if [[ "$name" == '-' ]]
    then
        name="$(gmktemp --suffix ".${extension}")"  || return $?
        stdout=y 
    fi
    local dir
    dir="$(dirname "$name")" 
    if test -z "$dir"
    then
        dir="$PWD" 
    fi
    dir="$(realpath "$dir")" 
    mkdir -p "$dir" || return $?
    name="$(basename "$name")" 
    if test -z "${name}"
    then
        name+="some"  || return $?
    fi
    [[ "$name" =~ '\.'${extension}'$' ]] || name+=".${extension}" 
    local f="${dir}/${name}" 
    if test -e "$f"
    then
        command rm "$f"
    fi
    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to ¬
                  write (the clipboard as ${class}) to ¬
                          (make new file at folder \"${dir}\" with properties ¬
                                  {name:\"${name}\"})" || return $?
    if test -n "$stdout"
    then
        cat "$f"
        command rm "$f"
    fi
}
```

Usage:

```
pngpaste some_path.png
```

```
pngpaste - | base64
```

---

Old answer (more minimal):

```
function pngpaste() {
    local name="${1}"

    [[ "$name" =~ '\.png$' ]] || name+=.png

    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to ¬
                  write (the clipboard as «class PNGf») to ¬
                          (make new file at folder \"$(pwd)\" with properties ¬
                                  {name:\"${name}\"})"
}

function jpgpaste() {
    local name="${1}"

    [[ "$name" =~ '\.jpg$' ]] || name+=.jpg

    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to ¬
                  write (the clipboard as JPEG picture) to ¬
                          (make new file at folder \"$(pwd)\" with properties ¬
                                  {name:\"${name}\"})"
}
```

Usage:

```
pngpaste a1.png
```

Comment: pngpaste also offers outputting the base64 of the image data (`-b`) flag, so this is not a full replacement, unfortunately.

Comment: @MartinBraun Well, convert the image to base64 using some other tool. There are dozens of such encoders.

Comment: Yes you are right, but as you might already know, I'd like to skip the output to the file system and go straight to base64 using stdout.